# What is the difference between builder and pageBuilder in the Go Router package?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router

In the Flutter [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package, there are apparently two ways of creating a new page, with either a `builder` or a `pageBuilder`:

```dart
GoRoute(
  name: 'Route',
  path: '/route',
  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
    const RouteView(...),
  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => 
    MaterialPage(
      child: const RouteView(...),
    ),
),
```

But what is the difference between them? They seem to do the same thing, only `pageBuilder` has a wrapper of `MaterialPage` on it, is that all? By the way, is a `MaterialPage` that useful?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've had this same question. From GoRouter's documentation this is all that I found:

> The builder is responsible for building the Widget to display on
> screen. Alternatively, you can use pageBuilder to customize the
> transition animation when that route becomes active. The default
> transition is used between pages depending on the app at the top of
> its widget tree, e.g. the use of MaterialApp will cause go_router to
> use the MaterialPage transitions. Consider using pageBuilder for
> custom Page class.

So I suppose the only useful difference I can deduce is that pageBuilder allows you to have a custom transition animation. Hope that helps.